# how to call phonegap function from serverside jsp

Tags: cordova

I have simply converted my mobile website into application using PhoneGap, but now I want to add some functionality like back button, getting contact list, email address and so on.

Here is what I have in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PhoneGap Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }



        var iabRef = null;

        function iabLoadStart(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        }

        function iabLoadStop(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        }

        function sandipAtClient() {
            alert('sandip');`
        }

        function iabClose(event) {
            alert(event.type);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            iabRef = window.open('http://................/index.jsp', '_blank', 'location=no');
            iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
            iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
        }

        function onBackKeyDown() {
            alert('sandy');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">



</body>

</html>
```

My index.jsp at server-side, I have to call function sandipAtClient() from index.jsp. `window.opener` and `parent.opener` are both not working. Please suggest how I should call sandipAtClient() from index.jsp.

Comment: The first thing you should be doing is attaching your `deviceready` listener. The `deviceready` event will always be the first to fire, so if you attach it and listen after `onload`, then there is no point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [longpolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) or [web-sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or polling.

But be aware, you will suck the battery empty with polling.